# Which capabilities are indexed?

Tags: opengl

According to [this](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glEnable.xhtml) `some of the GL's capabilities are indexed`. But I cannot understand which are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [OpenGL docs](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/GLAPI/glEnable), only `GL_BLEND` and `GL_SCISSOR_TEST` are indexed.

Note that it is valid to pass any `glEnable` valid value to `glEnablei` and vice versa:

> Any token accepted by glEnable or glDisable is also accepted by
>   glEnablei and glDisablei, but if the capability is not indexed, the
>   maximum value that index​ may take is zero.
>
> In general, passing an indexed capability to glEnable or glDisable
>   will enable or disable that capability for all indices, resepectively.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to google it but missed the official wiki. They could add that information into sdk docs. And yes, I saw that all capabilities are accepted by both versions of functions. I just could't find the answer to subject question from sdk docs.